# Laravel DB query a post with URL get

Tags: jquery, laravel

how can query one post in laravel  with url get ?

example :  http://localhost/lara/post/testpost

here , (testpost) is my post title in database and i want show this post information in single post file
how can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use implicit binding for this, it will automatically query your post model given the match against the last segment of the route. The :slug portion is simply telling it to look for the "slug" column on your post instead of the id.

```
<?php
// routes/web.php

Route::get('post/{post:slug}', function (App\Post $post) {
    return $post;
});
```

What you'll need to do is store a URL-friendly version of the name of your post in a new column called "slug", Laravel actually has a helper function for this called **str_slug** which you can find here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-slug

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Tim is a great solution and should be used, but in case you want to do some changes to your data before rendering, you can use this option as well. Note : I have skipped the model part to keep the explanation simpler.

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PostsController@getSinglePost')->name('single-post');
```

Then in your controller you can do this:

```
public function getSinglePost($slug){
   // use your DB query here using the slug into $post_data
   return view('single-post')->with('post_data',$post_data);
}
```

Using slug in a post is a good practice, but to keep your slug generation logic a bit cleaner I would recommend to have a structure like

```
http://example.com/<post_id>/<post_title_slug>
```

This would help you differentiate between posts even if the slug is same [ By chance ]

Hope this helps.